# how variable assignment to be processed in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I am confused about how variable assignment to be processed in shell.

For example:

```
  var=demo
  foo=$var
```

the $var will be expanded and the $foo will be "demo".

but if write as:

```
   count=0
   a_${count}=filename
```

the bash reports: ***a_0=filename: command not found***

From error message, we know a_${count} has expanded to a_0, so why variable assignment can't work? I found also if write in another way:

```
   count=0
   filename=a_${count}
```

everything will be ok, what difference between these??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that variable assignment happens before the expansion, if it is possible. If not, `a_$count=filename` is expanded and  understood as a command to run. You can make it into a command to delay the assignment by using `declare`:

```
declare a_$count=filename
```

Comment: That's where I confused:which stage the variable assignment happens. I found a great description in _Learning the bash shell (page 181, O'Reilly Press)_, but it never mention this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an expression on left hand side of variable assignment.

You can use `declare` instead:

```
declare a_${count}=filename
```

Then to verify:

```
echo "$a_0"
filename
```